# Extract element from list containing single item in python

Tags: python

I have a list containing only one element:

```
[u'\nUnited\napi\n\n0\n\n\n']
```

How can I extract only  the digit `0`?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you want to do. Find any numeric value in the string? Find any digit? Extract the fifth line? Something else? A single example without any description is far from enough to specify the problem.

Comment: i am looking for numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the same as you would from a string that is not in a list, except first you need to access the list item. Example:

```
mylist[0].strip().split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to extract that number

```
inp = [u'\nUnited\napi\n\n0\n\n\n']
re.search('(\d+)', inp[0).group(1)
```